# How to drop all iPhone/iPad retina/non-retina images in Asset catalog New Image set

Tags: ios, xcode, retina-display, asset-catalog

I'm creating a universal device app game. For iPhone 4s,5,5c,5s,6,6+ and iPad Retina's and non-retina's that support iOS 6.1+. I have about 40 images for the game different sizes. In Images.xcassets when I create a New Image Set, how do I place all iPhone 1x and iPad 1x non-retina and iPhone2x and iPad 2x Retina images for the Universal 1x, 2x, 3x with only 3 spaces?

Comment: What solution did you follow in the end ?

Comment: You can manage by this way:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483934/how-to-handle-iphone-screen-sizes-resolution-for-background-images

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the asset catalog window, you'll see options for both iPad and iPhone. Simply select them from the menu and more slots will appear targeted specifically for these devices.